# How does this javascript work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-load, jquery-post

I'm a javascript noob, and I don't understand why this works:

```
$().load('/my/url/', {my:data, more:data}, jsFunc());

function jsFunc()
{
    $("#myid").val("yep");
}
```

But not this:

```
$().load('/my/url/', {my:data, more:data}, function() {jsFunc()});

function jsFunc()
{
    $("#myid").val("yep");
}
```

I tried an $.ajax instead of $.load with the same result.  I will be passing the response data to jsFunc() and that is why I need jsFunc() inside the function.  I'm sure it is something simple I'm just not very experienced with javascript. Thanks.

Thanks again for all the help.  I decided to use $.post because it works best for the situation but now I'm having trouble with the response data.  My code looks like this:

```
$.post('/my/url/', {my:data, more:data}, function(data) {
    var strung = JSON.stringify(data)
    var parse = jQuery.parseJSON(strung)
    console.log(parse.some);}, 'json');
```

I'm logging to the console to see what is coming back for now and I will add the callback when I see the correct value logged.  The process I got from the jQuery api page, but it will only log `undefined`.  When I change `parse.some` to `parse` the console log will display the objects and I can select an element and see the correct key:value pair.  Any help would be sweet.

Comment: There's a difference between `load(func);`, and `load(func());`.

Comment: `$().load('/my/url/', {my:data, more:data}, jsFunc());` should not really "work". You are executing `jsFunc` immediately and pass the return value (which is `undefined`) as callback to `.load`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither works. The first one appears to work, because you call the function `jsFunc` immediately, it doesn't wait for any response.

If you create an empty jQuery object using `$()` and use the `load` method on that, it won't call the server because there is no element where it can put the result.

To specify the callback function you either use the name of a function:

```
$('#someElement').load('/my/url/', {my:data, more:data}, jsFunc);
```

or a function expression:

```
$('#someElement').load('/my/url/', {my:data, more:data}, function() { jsFunc(); });
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining that for me. That helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The first code block will simply call jsFunc() and return the results as the parameter to the load(..) method, which is odd because that parameter is supposed to be a callback function to fire when the load completes, but that works? The callback syntax is more in keeping with the second example (the one I believe you stated doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my second part:

My returned JSON data consisted of many objects, so I had to specify the index and the key to get the value to return.